# Pip install of scikit-learn: No matching distribiution found.

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I am trying to install scikit-learn through pip on Mac OSX. I have updated all of numpy, scipy and pip itself but when I type:

> "pip install scikit-learn -U"

I receive an error saying:

> "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for scikit-learn"

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score -3):

**To install scikit-learn use:**

`pip install sklearn`

Comment: The OP cannot install `scikit-learn`, how should `sklearn` help? `pip install -U sklearn` installs `scikit-learn` simply because `scikit-learn` is listed as a dependency.